# Properly create objects for a test user using factory girl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, omniauth, factory-bot

I am trying to test that notes that the user has created successful shows up on the user's personal page. However whenever I run my tests I get depreciation errors and a test that has failed to run properly due to user not being defined.

**user_page_spec.rb**

```
let (:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }


 describe "user note list" do
  before(:all) { 10.times { FactoryGirl.create(:note, user: user) } }
  after(:all) { Note.delete_all }
```

**factories.rb**

```
FactoryGirl.define do 
 factory :user do
   name "JowJebus"
   provider "twitter"
   uid "123456"

//matches omniauth fake user


factory :note do
  sequence(:title) { |n| "Note_#{n}" }
  sequence(:content) { |n| "Lorem ipsum ..... #{n}" }
  user
```

resulting error:

```
undefined method 'notes' for nil:NilClass
```

and the depreciation errors

```
This is deprecated behavior that will not be supported in RSpec 3.

'let' and 'subject' declarations are not intended to be called
in a 'before(:all)' hook, as they exist to define state that...
```

So obviously I am going about making the user for this test incorrectly, how does one go about doing this properly?

Thanks.

**note: The thing that I am testing does work. I just need help properly making the tests for it.**

Comment: I think it is not important for deprecated warning. What is 'notes'? There isn't any code about it. I guess it is in your user model. Can you post it?

Comment: Notes is another model. User `has_many` of them

Comment: Do you have any callbacks in your user model? Try to find when'notes' is called.

Comment: I would like to clarify that the function I am testing does work. I am just trying to properly test it for completeness and future sake.

Comment: copy the test that throws that error, it looks like user is not defined, but the spec isn't there to see what's missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The warning is because let keyword is intended to be used in a transactional context, while a before(:all) is an out-of-transaction scope.

The complete message is quite clear about this:

```
let and subject declarations are not intended to be called
in a `before(:all)` hook, as they exist to define state that
is reset between each example, while `before(:all)` exists to
define state that is shared across examples in an example group.
```

You can or change the `before(:all)` with a `before(:each)`, or:

```
before(:all) do
  user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
  10.times do
    FactoryGirl.create(:note, user: user)
  end
end
```

this also should work.